# jQuery if statement with variable mathematical operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am looking for something similar to this question [python if statement with variable mathematical operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847359/python-if-statement-with-variable-mathematical-operator) but in jQuery/Javascript

Essentially something like

```
var one = "4";

var two = "6";

var op = "==";

if (one op two) {
//do something
}
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could define a lot of binary functions:

```
var operators = {
    "==": function(a,b){return a==b;},
    "<=": function(a,b){return a<=b;},
    ">=": function(a,b){return a>=b;},
    "<": function(a,b){return a<b;},
    ">": function(a,b){return a>b;},
    …
};

var one = "4",
    two = "6",
    op = "==";
if (op in operators && operators[op](+one, +two)) {
    //do something
}
```

If you don't want to generate such a large object and have no complex functions, you also might be able to generate them on-the-fly (using a bit of `eval` magic):

```
var validOps = /^([!=<>]=|<|>)$/,
    operators = {};
function check(op, x, y) {
    if (arguments.length > 1)
        return check(op)(x, y);
    if (op in operators)
        return operators[op];
    if (validOps.test(op))
        return operators[op] = new Function("a","b","return a "+op+" b;");
    return function(a, b){return false;};
}

if (check("==", 4, 6)) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**eval()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.ASP) but it should be a string that could be evaluated to javascript to get the desired results.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/VQbq2/)**

```
if (eval(one + op + two)) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: the regular warnings on eval... be careful and make sure you know what your evaluating

Comment: Well this works, but I've never used eval before... what is so wrong with it?

Comment: Don't use eval. At least, use `eval("one"+op+"two")` so you only need to take care of validating operands

Comment: No need to downvote this answer.. This is perfektly correct .... but it uses eval.. @user1735913 you can eg. look here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270597/why-not-eval-json

Comment: Not my downvote, but any mention of eval generally gets you at least one.  @user1735913 details on the evils of eval http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: There are better approaches than using `eval`. I strongly recommend avoiding `eval` at all costs.

Comment: I will use the answer I selected as the answer.  But if I am only using this function to choose whether or not to hide or display a div based on the equation that is generated, is it really that bad to use eval in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an operation (otherwise known as a *function*) that you'd like to perform on two variables, then you simply need to define it:

```
var operations,
    a,
    b,
    op;
operations = {
    '==': function (a, b) {
        return a == b;
    },
    '&&': function (a, b) {
        return a && b;
    },
    '||': function (a, b) {
        return a || b;
    }
};
a = 4;
b = 6;
op = operations['=='];
if (op(a, b)) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like this recently and ended up writing a function to parse the operator.

Something like:

```
function checkLogic(one, op, two) {
    switch(op) {
        case '==':
            return one == two;
        // etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use Eval for this

```
 if(eval(one+op+two)){
//do something
}
```

Comment: ...and that's clearly why it exists.  :/