# How do I compute an array (or string) of numbers and mathematical operators

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, calculator

I am making a calculator and pushing/saving all the numbers and operators clicked to an array and a string.

I want to know which **approach** **is the best in this case**. Making a string or an array from the input **OR** a better approach I can't think of.

I want to compute the array or string. The string is giving wrong answers and I don't have a clue on how I can compute the array. The demo calculator is below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var inputArr = [];
  var inputStr = '';
  
  $('span').click(function(){
  $('#input').append($(this).text());
  //push to inputArr
   inputArr.push($(this).text());
  //add to inputStr
   inputStr += $(this).text();
  
  });
  
  //Get result
  $('.equals').click(function(){
    $('#result').text(inputArr);
    $('#result').append("<br/>" + parseInt(inputStr));
  });
  
  $('.clear').click(function(){
   // clear everything
  $('#input').text('');
  inputArr = [];
  inputStr = '';
  
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  background: #bbb;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.equals{
  width: 30%;
  background: #bbb;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>1</span>  <span>2</span>  <span>3</span>  <span>4</span>  <span>5</span> 
<br/>
<br/>

<span>6</span>  <span>7</span>  <span>8</span>  <span>9</span>  <span>0</span> 
<br/><br/>
   

<span>+</span><span>-</span><span>*</span><span>/</span><span class='clear'>clear</span>

<p class="equals"> = </p>

<p id="input"></p>

<p id='result'></p>
```

I tried using `parseInt(inputStr)` but it gives wrong answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make JavaScript evaluate a string and more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386753/how-to-make-javascript-evaluate-a-string-and-more)

Comment: An easy solution would be just to use `eval`, but some would say eval is evil, so the next solution is to parse your string and evaluate.. eg. -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276021/evaluating-a-string-as-a-mathematical-expression-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function takes either a string expression, or an array of characters that create an expression.

```js
function calculate(expression) {
  "strict mode";
  if (Array.isArray(expression))
    expression = expression.join("");
  var allowedChars = "1234567890%^*()-+/. ";
  for (var i = 0; i < expression.length; i++)
    if (allowedChars.indexOf(expression.charAt(i)) < 0)
      throw new Error("Invalid expression: unexpected '" + expression.charAt(i) + "' in '" + expression + "'");
  return eval(expression);
}

try {
  alert(calculate("4+4"));
  alert(calculate([7, "+", 9, "/", 34]));
  alert(calculate("45/3"));
  alert(calculate("100 * cheeseburger"));
} catch (e) {
  alert(e.message);
}
```

Here's why this is safe:

1. Improper use of eval opens up your code for injection attacks

   - In [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) `eval` is not able to introduce new variables to the surrounding scope. (As it's at the end of it's own function, nothing else is happening in that scope anyway.)
   - The function will throw an error if any character is present which is not part of a mathematical expression, making injection impossible.
2. With `eval`, debugging can be more challenging (no line numbers, etc.)

   - In this case the function throws an Error, which includes a line number. The `eval`'d  code is only so a single line, so this is not relevant.
3. `eval`'d code executes more slowly (no opportunity to compile/cache eval'd code)

   - In this case there is nothing to compile/cache, so this is not an issue.

Comment: Finally, some logical advice on how to safely use eval, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` doesn't evaluate a string with mathematical operations. `eval` will do this. If you are worried about the safety of using `eval`, you will have to write a calculator function that parses a string and observes order of operations (a much more involved task). I see no reason to keep both an array AND a string. Either will suffice.

Working code snippet with minimal modifications:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var inputStr = '';
  
  $('span').click(function(){
  $('#input').append($(this).text());
  //add to inputStr
   inputStr += $(this).text();
  
  });
  
  //Get result
  $('.equals').click(function(){
    // or however you want to format it
    $('#result').text(inputStr + ' = ' + eval(inputStr));
  });
  
  $('.clear').click(function(){
   // clear everything
  $('#input').text('');
  $('#result').text('');
  inputArr = [];
  inputStr = '';
  
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  background: #bbb;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.equals{
  width: 30%;
  background: #bbb;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>1</span>  <span>2</span>  <span>3</span>  <span>4</span>  <span>5</span> 
<br/>
<br/>

<span>6</span>  <span>7</span>  <span>8</span>  <span>9</span>  <span>0</span> 
<br/><br/>
   

<span>+</span><span>-</span><span>*</span><span>/</span><span class='clear'>clear</span>

<p class="equals"> = </p>

<p id="input"></p>

<p id='result'></p>
```