# Concatenate operator in math operation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I want to create a random generator of math operations. I'm trying with ASCII codes but what happens is that it just concatenate the operands and operators as a String. Anyone has a suggestion for this?

```js
let a = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
let b =  Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
let ascCode = Math.floor(Math.random()* (46 - 42)) + 42
let op = String.fromCharCode(ascCode)
let c = a + `${op}` + b;
 
console.log(c)
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Can you give some more information on what you need? What is the output you're expecting?

Comment: I want a generator of random basic math operations

Comment: If `a` = 1 and `b` = 2, what do you want `c` to be?

Comment: Note that your operation range includes `,` -- how would you want that handled?

Comment: As Devon's comment suggests, this is a case for `eval`.

Comment: Do you mean [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12961206/1048572)?

Comment: @Bergi: I'm just curious, why do you link to a question that you yourself marked as a duplicate of another, rather than to that second one?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Oh, didn't notice that. I just had the link to my own answer in my bookmarks...

Comment: eval worked. I filtered the values 44, 46.

Comment: one way to avoid eval is to use function with switch case - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rPWqaN?editors=1010 , as there are limited number of operators

Comment: @Devon et al: this is not a duplicate of that question.  While the `eval` answers might help, they don't really address the basic question of "I want to create a random generator of math operations."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is similar to things discussed in the comments.  It is a different, non-`eval` way of generating random math operations:

```js
const ops = {
  '+': (a, b) => a + b,
  '-': (a, b) => a - b,
  '*': (a, b) => a * b,
  '/': (a, b) => a / b,
  '%': (a, b) => a % b,
  '>': (a, b) => a > b,
  '<': (a, b) => a < b,
  // etc
}

const randomOperation = ((ops) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(ops)
  const randomOpKey = () => keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)]
  const evalOp = (key, a, b) => ops[key](a, b)
  
  return () => {
    const op = randomOpKey()
    const a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
    const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
    return {
      expression: `${a} ${op} ${b}`,
      result: evalOp(op, a, b)
    }
  }
})(ops)


// demo

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  let {expression, result} = randomOperation()
  console.log(`${expression} = ${result}`)
}
```

Note that what `randomOperation` returns is objects with two properties: `expression` as a string, and `result` as a value, which will be numeric or boolean.  The demo code shows one way to use it.  You have to manually maintain the list of operations, which is different than with the `eval` solutions.

I don't know what better suits your needs, but this should show that there are reasonable non-`eval` solutions possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

> The eval() function evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.

```js
let a = 1
let b = 2
let ascCode = Math.floor(Math.random()* (46 - 42)) + 42
let op = String.fromCharCode(ascCode)
let c = eval(a + `${op}` + b);

console.log(c)
```

But eval can be troublesome.

> eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your webpage / extension. More importantly, a third-party code can see the scope in which eval() was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks in ways to which the similar Function is not susceptible.
>
> eval() is also slower than the alternatives, since it has to invoke the JS interpreter, while many other constructs are optimized by modern JS engines.

[msdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!)

Another solution would be to use some if:

```
let a = 1
let b = 2
let ascCode = Math.floor(Math.random()* (46 - 42)) + 42
let op = String.fromCharCode(ascCode)

let c = 0;
if (op == "*")
c = a + b;
if (op == "+")
c = a + b;
if (op == "-")
c = a - b;

/*etc*/ 

console.log(c)
```

or even a map where keys are operators and values are functions:

```
let a = 1
let b = 2
let ascCode = Math.floor(Math.random()* (46 - 42)) + 42
let op = String.fromCharCode(ascCode)

let operators = {
'+': (a, b) => a + b,
'-': (a, b) => a - b,
'*': (a, b) => a * b,
'/': (a, b) => a / b, // handle zero!
'%': (a, b) => a % b // handle zero!
};

console.log(operators[op](a,b))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could use (though this is definitely not a good practice), is `eval()`, which evaluates a string as javascript code.

(Another word of warning, `eval` is evil and shouldn't be used in production)

```js
let a = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
let b =  Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
let ascCode = Math.floor(Math.random()* (46 - 42)) + 42
let op = String.fromCharCode(ascCode)
let c = eval(a + `${op}` + b);
 
console.log(c)
```

Comment: @aloisdg Well I'd even call it a bit less detailed :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use built-in function `eval()`

```js
let operators = ['+','-','*','/','%'];
    let number1 = 5;
    let number2 = 4;
    function getRandomOperation(){
     let randOpeator = operators[Math.floor(Math.random() * operators.length)];
     return eval(`${number1} ${randOpeator} ${number2}`);
    }
console.log(getRandomOperation());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should evalute expression, using javascript `eval` function. It expects string as input.

```
const result = eval(c);

console.log(result);
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Answer (score -1):

I presume it happens because you are using concatenation when one from concatenated values is a string:

let op = String.fromCharCode(ascCode)

To obtain a number under variable c you have to make sure that ${op} is number as well.

Comment: There's a problem with this: `op` should be interpreted as an infix operator, not an operand.